# How to iterate through javascript object and run a function on each value

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I am new to JS.

I set up a Saved Search in NetSuite that gives us the image fields (containing URLs) of our items. I am now setting up a script in NS which tests these fields to see what item fields return 404 (i.e. need to be fixed).

My question is, how to set up function `imageURLValidator` to iterate through the field values of function `searchItems`?

Below is my start to the process but obviously has much incorrect syntax.

```
function imageURLValidator() {  
    var searchResults = searchItems('inventoryitem','customsearch529');

    var url = '';
    var item = '';
    var field = '';

    //insert loop here to iterate over items in searchResults array

    //loop through items
    for (var i = 0, i > searchResults[inventoryObject].length, i++) {
        item = searchResults.[inventoryObject].[i];

        //loop through fields in item
        for (var f = 2, f > item.length, f++) {
            field = item[f];

            //check URL via item field's value 
            var code = checkURL(item[field].getvalue([field]));

            //generate error based on code variable 
            createErrorRecord(code,item,field)
        }
    }
}

function searchItems(type, searchid) {
    //defining some useful variables that we will use later
    var inventoryArray = [];
    var count = 0;

    //loading the saved search, replace the id with the id of the search you would like to use
    var inventoryItemSearch = nlapiLoadSearch(type, searchid);

    //run the search
    var inventoryItemResults = inventoryItemSearch.runSearch();

    //returns a js array of the various columns specified in the saved search
    var columns = inventoryItemResults.getColumns();

    //use a do...while loop to iterate through all of the search results and read what we need into one single js object

    do {
        //remember the first time through the loop count starts at 0
        var results = inventoryItemResults.getResults(count, count + 1000.0);

        //we will now increment the count variable by the number of results, it is now no longer 0 but (assuming there are more than 1000 total results) will be 1000 
        count = count + results.length;

        //now for each item row that we are on we will loop through the columns and copy them to the inventoryObject js object
        for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++){
            var inventoryObject = {};
            for (var j=0; j<columns.length; j++){
                inventoryObject[columns[j].getLabel()] = results[i].getValue(columns[j]);
            }

            //then we add the inventoryObject to the overall list of inventory items, called inventoryArray
            inventoryArray.push(inventoryObject);
        }

    //we do all of this so long as the while condition is true.  Here we are assuming that if the [number of results]/1000 has no remainder then there are no more results        
    } while (results.length != 0 && count != 0 && count % 1000 == 0);

    return inventoryArray;
}

function checkURL(url) {
    var response = nlapiRequestURL(url);
    var code = response.getCode();

    return code;
}

function createErrorRecord(code,item,field) {
    if (code == 404){
        //create error record
        var errorRecord = nlapiCreateRecord('customrecord_item_url_error');
        errorRecord.setFieldValue('custrecord_url_error_item', item);
        errorRecord.setFieldValue('custrecord_url_error_image_field', field);
    }
}
```

Comment: What issue you are facing?
Note : for loop is suppose to be like `for(initialization;condition;increment)`
check if thats the issue..

Comment: You should not expect your code to work as long as their are syntax errors.  Fix those first then see what it does.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference is not a bad place to start.

Comment: what does the function *nlapiLoadSearch* do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I can see **searchResults** variable will be empty while looping. As your call to **searchItems** function is async. Which will take some time to execute because I guess it will fetch data from API. By the time it returns value, your loop also would have bee executed. You can test this by putting an alert(searchResults.length) or console.log(searchResults.length). For that you need to use **callback function**

Also even if you get the results in **searchResults**. The loop you are doing is wrong. The array you will get is like [{},{},{}] i.e. array of objects.

To access you'll need

```
for (var i = 0, i > searchResults.length, i++) {
        var inventoryObject = searchResults[i] // your inventoryObject 

    for(var key in inventoryObject){
        item = inventoryObject[key]; // here you will get each item from inventoryObject 
        //loop through fields in item
        for (var f = 2, f > item.length, f++) {
            field = item[f];

            //check URL via item field's value 
            var code = checkURL(item[field].getvalue([field]));

            //generate error based on code variable 
            createErrorRecord(code,item,field)
        }
    }
}
```

And yes welcome to Javascript

Comment: Great! That is helpful. It was the (var key in inventoryObject) syntax I was looking for.